# There is $N$ so that $\liminf S_n \leq S_n \leq \limsup S_n$ when $n > N$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n = -2$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n = 1$, there exists $N$ so that $-2 \leq S_n \leq 1$ when $n > N$.

I think this is obvious. But how to prove it?

Comment: What if $S_n = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} (-1)^n (1 + \frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: If you have an additional property, such as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (S_{n+1}-S_n)=0$, you can prove that $\forall N, \exists n>N, -2 < S_n < 1$. But that's not $\forall N, \forall n > N$.